# Why wont my footer stick? How can I get my text to stop dissappearing behind contact form?

Tags: html, css

I think part of my code is being overwritten - I can't get this footer to fix at the bottom of the screen.

Also, the text is disappearing behind the contact form when I shrink the screen size.

Any advice on how to prevent or fix either of these issues would be greatly appreciated.

[image: screenshot of contact page]

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-3 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.py-2 {
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
}

.grid,
.features-main .grid,
.showcase,
.contact {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.features-head,
.contact {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Contact Section -->
<section class="contact">
  <div class="container grid">
    <div class="contact-text">
      <h1>Get In Touch.</h1>
      <p>We would love to hear from you! Please contact us regarding queries, additional info, suggestions or feedback on the site.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contact-form card">
      <h2>Contact Us Today</h2>
      <form>
        <div class="form-basics">
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-basics">
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-basics">
          <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message" required>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="button">
      </form>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer class="footer bg-dark py-2">
  <div class="container grid grid-3">
    <div>
      <h1>Snowden
      </h1>
      <p>Copyright Culhane &copy; 2021</p>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="subscribe.html">Subscribe</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="social">
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I am new to this, so if you require any additional info please let me know. Currently following a few tutorials, so they may be overlapping, causing problems.

Comment: are you using a framework?

Comment: @tacoshy no, just following a html & css tutorial from scratch on YouTube

Comment: In the coe you provided I see no declaration that would make the footer stick in the first palce? what exactly have you tried so far? where are you stuck at?

Answer (score 0):

For the Footer to be at the bottom;

```
 .footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
    }
```

Set a height to footer and set bottom margin of that equal height so that other elements doesn't get below the footer;

Comment: Thank you, but this covers some of the content on my other pages. Is there a way to prevent this? Do you know how to stop the text disappearing behind the contact form also?

Comment: Yes, like I mentioned, set a height to the footer and then set that height value as margin bottom on the body element. Then you'll have the necessary space for the footer. There are better solutions than setting footer to absolute, but you'd have to change how you have set your layout, also need to share more of the code.